# Selecting the correct ILI9341 Drive Mode for STM32F407 using FSMC

Tags: stm32, driver, display, tft, ili9341

I have selected the STM32F405 for my next project. With this controller, I am planning to drive a 240x320-TFT with an ILI9341 display controller by using the STM32's internal FSMC interface.
I have not decided exactly which display I am going to take but I have chosen two almost identical TFTs with ILI9341 for the selection that only differ in terms of FPC pinout.

The FSMC interface of the microcontroller can either drive displays in 8-bit or 16-bit mode. In terms of display speed, I would like to adhere to 16bit mode.

So, I have been looking at the different drive modes of the ILI9341 and have found out that there are 15 modes, which can be selected through IM0-IM3 (page 27).

Datasheet: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9341.pdf

However, I am currently in the process of designing the schematics and I am not sure which 8080-mode I have to select. 
What is the difference between 8080-I 16bit and 8080-II 16bit (p.70-75)? I have looked at the diagrams and have found that different channels of the datachannels D[17:0] are used. But I can not imagine that this is the only difference. Can anyone tell me or recommend the appropritae mode that complies with the STM32's FSMC interface? As I am not using the STM32F427/37 direct TFT-driving is not relevant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the table on page 26. The difference is in the pin allocations on the 18-bit data bus. In 8, 9 and 16 bit interface mode, there are more data bus pins than required, and the two modes select which pins are left unused. In 8080-I mode, the data is aligned to the least significant bit of the bus and the most significant bits are left unused, while in 8080-II mode the data is aligned to the most significant bit, and the least significant bits are unused.